# HAProxy and NGINX problems with private IP

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I have HAProxy setup, and I have no problem pointing it to the public IP of my App server, but I can't get it to point to the Private IP. I get a "503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request." error

These are my settings:

haproxy.cfg

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        maxconn 4096
        user haproxy
        group haproxy

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen webfarm 173.255.222.100:80
       mode http
       stats enable
       stats auth deploy:d3pl0y
       balance roundrobin
       cookie JSESSIONID prefix
       option httpclose
       option forwardfor
       server App1 192.168.133.136:80 cookie App1 check
```

nginx.conf (for app server)

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  4;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /opt/ruby/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

server {
     listen 192.168.133.136:80;
     port_in_redirect off;
     server_name localhost;
     root /var/www/current/public;
     passenger_enabled on;
     rack_env production;
     if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html){
             rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html break;
     }


     if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
             set $host_without_www $1;
             rewrite ^(.*)$ http://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
     }
        }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

503 means that the server failed the checks, which are simply TCP in your config. I suspect that your traffic is being filtered between the haproxy LB and the server, or that the server cannot respond to the LB.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the backend definition in your haproxy.conf? You should define a default backend and put server App1 192.168.133.136:80 cookie App1 check in there and  enable Haproxy stats to check whats going on. Did you also check your firewall and made sure that 192.168.133.136 responds to the server where haproxy is installed?

Please check the following article on [load balancing with haproxy](https://www.cevapsepeti.com/yazilar/how-to-put-nginx-behind-haproxy/).